# How can I use several triggers for the same snippet?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I have made a snippet which I want to give different triggers, so instead of say `trigger` I also want to trigger it with `myothertrigger`:

```
snippet trigger "just an example" 
my text ...
endsnippet
```

Is there an easy way to do this instead of copying the snippet?

**Edit:** To be clear, I am using [**UltiSnips**](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), but if there is a better plugin I might look into that.

Comment: The answer would depend on the snippet engine you're using. With mu-template you could have include one snippet from another, copy the snippet file under a different name or just create a symbolic link. I'm not sure the other engines could permit it. May be if some day they come to support snippet inclusion from "caller" snippets.

Perhaps you could define the core of your snippet in a python or viml function and have your snippets call the same function?

Comment: The question is tagged as `plugin-ultisnips`, so I would assume the OP is using ultisnips.

Comment: My mistake ^^'
(µTemplate isn't better, just very different, older, and more suited toward my needs (I'm maintaining it): I've root snippets that behave as functions that I can call with different options to produce different but very close things.Eg in C++ I have snippets for base-class, value-class, exception-class... that all depend on the same set of class-snippet+function-snippet+... But as I told, the syntax is completely different, and the placeholder feature is less ergonomic than the one you're used to. Doing what you're looking for would be easy, but not necessity worth a migration)

Comment: If you switch to Shougo's `neosnippet` plugin, its syntax has an `alias` keyword for this very purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do this in UltiSnips. There is an [open feature-request on Github](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/235) for it though. Personally, I would like an alias functionality for triggers as indicated [here](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/359) too.

Let's hope SirVer (the maintainer of UltiSnips) will think so too and include it in the future :)

Answer (score 6):

Although there is no specific syntax for aliases you can achieve the same effect by using `post_jump`:

```
# c.snippets
global !p
def expand(snip):
    if snip.tabstop != 1:
        return
    vim.eval('feedkeys("\<C-R>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()\<CR>")')
endglobal

snippet incstdlib "#include <stdlib.h>" !b
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit(), malloc(), free() */
$0
endsnippet

post_jump "expand(snip)"
snippet incexit "#include <stdlib.h>" !b
incstdlib$1
endsnippet
```

In this snippets file the trigger `incexit` is an "alias" of trigger `incstdlib`. In reality `incexit` expands to `incstdlib` and the `expand(snip)` is called when UltiSnips moves to the tabstop `$1`. The `expand(snip)` just executes the VimScript function `UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet` which will expand `incstdlib` into it's final expanded form `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Another options is to use UltiSnips regular expression support instead:

```
snippet "inc(true|false|bool)" "#include <stdbool.h>" r
#include <stdbool.h> /* true, false */
endsnippet
```

Here you will have three triggers `inctrue`, `incfalse` and `incbool` that are effectively the same. The only drawback is that autocompletion plugins like YouCompleteMe will not autocomplete those.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin [neosnippet.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim) support multiple trigger by keyword ['alias'](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim/master/doc/neosnippet.txt),
e.g. there have three triggers `if` `myif` `myif2`:

```
snippet     tcl::if
options     head
alias       if myif myif2
abbr tcl::if
    if { ${0:#:TARGET} } {
    }
```